# Passed name variable won't load new xml content

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml, variables

I have passed a dog's name from Pg1 to Pg2. I have put comments in the code below to explain what is happening step by step. My code works until the last function, which is supposed to search the girls.xml for the dog's name and load the related node into the profile on Pg2.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions you may have to improve my code as well. Be kind I'm self taught :-)

This is how the **litters.xml** file is formatted

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <litter>
    <litter_id>201704</litter_id>
    <dogs_mom>June Bug</dogs_mom>
    <dogs_dad>Oscar</dogs_dad>
  </litter>
```

This is how the **girls.xml** file is formatted

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<breeder>
  <girls>
    <dog>
        <dogs_breeding_name>Adora</dogs_breeding_name>
        <profile>
            <![CDATA[<strong>Adora</strong> is a second generation puppy. Adora lives in a guardian home. ]]>
        </profile>          
       </dog>
    </girls>
</breeder>
```

On **pg1.html** the name of a Dog's Mom has been clicked (litters.xml) and passed to pg2.html

```
$(".thumb-but-link").click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
var i = $(e.currentTarget).text();
window.location.href = '../xml/pg2.html' + '#' + i;
});
```

The **pg2.html** file loads the **girls.xml** file

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "../xml/girls.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: findDog
   });
```

The findDog function loads the girls node

```
       function findDog(xml){
         $(xml).find('girls').each(function () {
         girlsXml = $(this);
```

Then it uses an if statement to check to see if a new dog name was passed from **pg1.html**, if no name was passed, it loads the default (first dog) in the **girls.xml** file into the dog profile on the page.

```
        if(window.location.hash.substring(1)) {
                    var i = location.hash.match(/^#?(.*)$/)[1];
                    var x = girlsXml.find('dog:contains("i")');
                    loadClickedContent(x)
                 }else{
                    var x = girlsXml.find('dog').first();
                    loadClickedContent(x)
            }
          }); 
       }


    function loadClickedContent(x) {
        girlsXml.find(x).each(function () {
            var x = $(this);
            var dogsBreedingName = x.   find('dogs_breeding_name').text();
            var profileName = x.find('profile').text();

            $("#breedingNameHolder").empty();
            $("#profileHolder").empty();

            $("#breedingNameHolder").append(dogsBreedingName);
            $("#profileHolder").append(profileName);
        }); 
    }   
 </script>
```

So...

**Pg1.html** thumb-but-link" is passing the dog's name from litters.xml to **Pg2.html** correctly.

**Pg2.html** the girls.xml is loading correctly

**Pg2.xml** is able to load the default dog from girls.xml into the profile

**Pg2.html** the if statement is able to read the dog's name from Pg1.html

**Pg2.html** the else statement is able to read the default dog from girls.xml. It then calls the loadClickedContent function and loads the default dog into the profile.

I think my problem might be when I call the loadClickedContent function, from the if statement, it isn't loading the new content. Is it possible that it isn't in the right format? I have tried putting .html() and .text() at the end but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you're looking for the dog's name, you didn't actually put it in the search, you just put the letter `i`, try the code below where the variable `i` is concatenated into the string to find the required dog.

```
var x = girlsXml.find('dog:contains("'+i+'")');
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried your solution but it is giving me this error message. "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. Expected '}' to end an object literal."